# Querying from ref objectid

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 models `User`, `Department`, and `Ticket`.

```js
const TicketSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
```

```js
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   department: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Department'
    }
```

I'm trying to query tickets from a department in `Ticket` Model, how can I do that?

example: `Ticket.find({ author.department: req.user.department }).populate('author')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "author",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "author"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$author"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "author.department": req.user.department
    }
  }
])
```

[Test Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8szdYW5c0Dy)